# How to force a Swift compiler error with a custom message

Tags: swift, compilation, compiler-errors

I'm working on a change to a library that exposes a new method, but it's only available for a particular architecture. If you call it from an ARM assembly, for instance, I would like a compile-time error instructing you to use a compiler conditional to exclude the call. Is there any way to accomplish this? Something like the following:

```
public func x86Only() {
    #if arch(x86_64)
    // Do something here
    #else
        compiler_fail("x86Only() can only be called from x86_64 architecture")
    #end
}
```

Does something like the (invented) `compiler_fail()` above exist for Swift?

`fatalError()` doesn't work as nicely, because it triggers a runtime assertion failure, rather than catching the user error at compile-time.

Answer (score 4):

Since Swift 4.2, you can use `#warning` to display yellow warnings in Xcode and `#error` to display red build-time errors.

For example, this code will display a warning with a custom message:

```
#warning("Fix this code before release!")
```

These also work inside conditional compiling blocks, which is what you are looking for.

```
#if os(macOS)
#warning("This library is for iOS only")
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for something like "compile time assertions"?

Unfortunately, this is not yet implemented. But there's a corresponding thread in the "swift-evolution" list:

https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20151221/003837.html